# Как выровнять один блок относительно второго и по центру

Tags: html

```css
.header {
 background: #ccc;
 width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
}
.header-menu {
 background: #000;
 width: 960px;
 height: 90px;
 margin: ;

 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Home</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="header-menu">
   
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .header-menu - margin:0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
 background: #ccc;
 width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
}
.header-menu {
 background: #000;
 width: 40%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Home</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="header-menu">
   
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```